# how to efficiently cythonize the "vectorize" function (numpy library) - python

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, cython

as the title suggets, I'd like to efficiently cythonize the `numpy.vectorize` function, which, to the core, is simplyfying this piece below (the complete function is way too long to post but the majority of the time is spent here):

```
    def func(*vargs):
        for _n, _i in enumerate(inds):
            the_args[_i] = vargs[_n]
        kwargs.update(zip(names, vargs[len(inds):]))
        return self.pyfunc(*the_args, **kwargs)
```

I have read these guides (http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html and http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html) which are very useful but my knowledge of C is way too narrow to use them to a fraction of their potential.

how would you go about it ? [Python 3.5.1, Cython 0.25a, Numpy 1.10.4]

Comment: I doubt if you can. You're iterating over an array with an unknown number of dimensions and calling a python function that returns an unknown type. You've got to be pretty flexible in the code and so Cython is unlikely to help.

Comment: Are you stuck with `pyfunc`, a blackbox python function that cython can''t convert to `c`?

Comment: the stuff I am trying is slowing or not working. I thought about defining ndarray type like in one of the guides `np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] ,
cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] h = ...` but it does not seem to be working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you show is just a bit of dancing to deal with `kwargs`.  Note the comment at the head of that block in `vectorize.__call__`.  With simpler arguments it just sets `func = self.pyfunc`.

The actual work is done in the last line:

```
self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
```

which does

```
outputs = ufunc(*inputs)
< return dtype conversion >
```

`ufunc` is, in most cases, `frompyfunc(func, len(args), nout)`.

So stripped of all this Python cover,  it comes down to

```
np.frompyfunc(your_func, n, m)(args)
```

and `frompyfunc` is a compiled function.  I suspect that function uses `nditer` (the `c` version) to broadcast the arguments, and feed the values as scalars to `your_func`.  I discussed the use of `nditer` with `cython` in another recent SO.

In sum, as long as `your_func` is an impentrable (or general) python function, there's nothing `cython` can do to improve on this.  The iteration is already being handled in compiled code.